# If $f$ is an entire function and $|f'(z)| < |f(z)|$ then how do I prove that there exists some positive real $a$ s.t. $|f(z)| \le a e^{|z|}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function such that $|f'(z)| < |f(z)|$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Show that there exists a positive real number $a$ s.t. $|f(z)| \le a e^{|z|}$.

What I have tried so far is:

We know that $0 \le |f'(z)|< |f(z)|$. This implies $f$ doesn't vanish in $\mathbb{C}$. Hence, $g(z) = \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$ is an entire function.

We know $|g(z)|<1$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Using Liouville's theorem, we get: $g \equiv c$ for some $c \in \mathbb{C}$. This implies $f'(z) = cf(z)$.

Since $f$ is entire, we can write a power series expansion about $0$ with infinite radius of convergence. $$
       f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n}z^{n} \quad \;\text{in}\; \mathbb{C}
      $$ We know $f'(z) = cf(z)$, we thus have $$
     \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n a_{n}z^{n-1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c a_{n}z^{n}.  
      $$ Equating coefficients, we get $$
      ca_{0} = a_1\quad  ca_1 = 2a_2 \quad \dots  \quad ca_{k} = (k+1)a_{k+1}.
      $$  Thus, $a_{k}=\frac{c^{k}a_{0}}{k!}$. Hence, $$
      f(z)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n}z^{n} = a_{0} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(cz)^{n}}{n!} = a_0e^{cz}.
      $$ Then,
\begin{align*}
       |f(z)| &= |a_0||e^{cz}|\\
       &= |a_0| e^{\mathrm{Re}(cz)}\\
       &\le |a_0| e^{c|z|}.
      \end{align*}

I'm not quite getting what I want in the end and need a little help to finish the solution.

Comment: Note that $c$ may be non-real. So the last inequality may not be true. Write $|cz|$ in place of $c|z|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have it, now just use the fact that you already know $c<1$ and the fact that the exponential is increasing.

Comment: Thank you, Nick. You're right. I just missed that $c< 1$.

Comment: Note that you only know $|c|<1$, but this is enough.